# Remove the marker from the ArrayList: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android

I have a checkboxlist where the user can select some routes then a reponse is being getting from the server. I have method gotoLocation to upadte the location of the markers as well to add a new marker in the map when a new one is being inserted into the table on the serverside with the same route.

I tried it before with `HashMap<Integer, Marker> as <id, marker>` but I had problem to add a new marker of the new request to the map so I tried it with `ArrayList<Integer, String>` and it works but I am getting now the error below when I try to remove a marker from the map.

How can I fix it?

**Error:**

```
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919): Process: com.bustracker, PID: 29919
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at com.bustracker.Map.gotoLocation(Map.java:132)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at com.bustracker.Map.onNewIntent(Map.java:314)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1224)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2833)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2846)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2855)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:177)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1520)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
07-16 00:19:05.663: E/AndroidRuntime(29919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

**Code:**

```
    private void gotoLocation(int id, double lat, double lng,
            String route_direct) {
         ......
        // Update the location.
        for(Iterator<MapItem> it = mapItemList.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            //Line 132.
            MapItem item1 = it.next();

            if(item1.getId() == id){
                marker = item1.getMarker();
                marker.remove();
                //int index = mapItemList.indexOf(item1);
                it.remove();
                ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title(
                        route_direct).position(ll);
                marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                 map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 11));
                MapItem mapItem = new MapItem(id, marker);
                mapItemList.add(mapItem);

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: You're better off sticking with `HashMap<Integer, Marker>`.  Switching to using an ArrayList will just make it harder on you, as you can't do a lookup based on the key.

Comment: @DanielNugent: Yor are right I got it to work with the HashMap. well one of the problems was, that the table id was incremented by one when the row was updated. I have not noticed that  I thought it is not being incremted.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is caused by  `mapItemList.add(mapItem);`. Every modification to the collection, while you are iterating over it, will cause this exception. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

> For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is
>   iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator
>   will throw this exception.

To fix you can use either use the `ListIterator` instead of the `Iterator` (to retrieve it use `listIterator()`), and use `iterator.add(mapItem);` or you can use a temporary `ArrayList` where you will add the items you create while you are looping, and use `addAll` to add the whole content to the your `mapItemList` after the loop ends